# jQuery .ajax pass the whole JavaScript array to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
tdata = new Array();  
tdata['id'] = "helloid";  
tdata['name'] = "helloname";  
tdata['location'] = "hellolocation";  
tdata['about'] = "helloabout";  
tdata['company'] = "hellocompany";  
tdata['website'] = "hellowebsite";  

$.ajax({
    url: 'export.setsession.php',
        data: { tdata: tdata.id 
    },
    type: 'post',
    success: function (output) {
        //$(location).attr('href', 'index.php');
        alert("girdsposted");
    }
});
```

The above is working just fine but I would like to pass the array as a whole if that is possible like data: { tdata: tdata } as opposed to only passing the id. Is this possible to do or is there an alternative? I have not yet been able to get the whole array into PHP is some form I can read...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using the [JSON.stringify() method](http://www.json.org/js.html), which will transform your tdata element into a JSON string :

```
data: JSON.stringify(tdata)
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a JSON string with:

```
JSON.stringify({ json: tdata });
```

and then convert it to a PHP array with:

```
json_decode($data);
```